# No Resource found - Google Play Services version - Old Android Project

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am actually trying to open an old android project, which I have to edit. The project was coded back in Oct 14.

Now I downloaded the project from Github, and opened it in Android Studio via Import. When I try to build or debug, I get the error:

> Error:(113, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').

After hours of searching in similar topics I did not find a solution that helped me.

Has anyone an idea how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this below Methods,I hope this will help you.

**Edit 1:**

Import Eclipse Project to Android Studio:

1.Start Android Studio and close any open Android Studio projects.

2.From the Android Studio menu click File > New > Import Project. Alternatively, from the Welcome screen, click Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.).

3.Select the Eclipse ADT project folder with the AndroidManifest.xml file and click Ok.

4.Select the destination folder and click Next.

5.Select the import options and click Finish.

6.The import process prompts you to migrate any library and project dependencies to Android Studio, and add the dependency declarations to the build.gradle file.
For detail description try this link

https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html#migrating_from_eclipse

**Edit2:**

Remove the line in the project.properties file that was making reference to the ***google_play_services_version***.

All the Best.

Comment: This is exactly what i did, i removed the line in the project.properties before. With this line i could not import it. After deleting, i could import, but now the above error with google play services is showing.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of that

Comment: this "works" in the way that the old error doesn't show up, but a new one: (Gradle project sync failed)

|| Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0

|| Install Repository and sync project
|| Show in File
|| Show in Project Structure dialog

|| When i click on "install repository and sync" nothing happens.

|| Screen: https://ibb.co/hrjoFb

Comment: Restart Android Studio And Try Again the Installation

Comment: Did this, and did some other fixes from threads in StackOverflow too, but now it is an other error which is driving me crazy. the thing is: i am actually trying to bring this android project to life for days now and im in a circle with errors. if i fix one, then another one appears. and if i fix two more, the first probably will come back again. in my oppinion its only a version/gradle problem. here a screen of the newest error: https://ibb.co/h6jr1G

if you could help me out, this would be worth some money for me.

Comment: Change these Attributes 
compileSdkVersion ,
minSdkVersion ,
targetSdkVersion , and appcompat version(compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:xxxxxx') in your gradle file under the application directory

Comment: Thank you, this leads me to the next error(s): This is the next one, why it doesnt compile: https://ibb.co/bY2QTw

And also in my Java Files all "R." are now red.

Thank you so much GuruCharan for helping me, if we fix this together i will give you some donations via paypal :-)

Comment: :-D Chill Bro I'll do my best, If the Project is not Confidential Share the source code.More Hands more Power.

Comment: No Problem: goo.gl/Geaorw - This is a version published in 2015, my job is to edit and add some features - but i even cant get it run :(

If you got problems with the first compile errors that occur (crunch error, manifest error etc.) when you open it, please contact me. i can give you my mobile number or email

Comment: Ok lemme see that project,anyway share your email

Comment: ProjectGit: goo.gl/Geaorw - Mail: paulfrank9999@gmail.com